# SQLAlchemy Crashes Script when using Session.Merg()

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a script that uses the amazon api to look up items based on upc and then save them to a MySql database.
For some reason when I use `session.merge` it randomly crashes the script.
Using `session.add` works but when there is a duplicate in the database the script errors on the commit.

Also when the script crashes it does not output any kind of error.

Is there a reason why session.merge crashes the script or a way that session.add can update duplicate records on session.commit?

Thanks,

Code:

```
upcs = <List of UPC Codes>
# Breaking the list into groups of 10 for Amazon API
group = 10
sub_upcs = [upcs[i:i+group] for i in range(0, len(upcs), group)]

for sub_upc in sub_upcs:
    try:
        products = amazon.lookup(ItemId=','.join(sub_upc), IdType='UPC', SearchIndex='All')
    except AsinNotFound as e:
        print("UPC Not Found")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    if type(products) is list:
        for product in products:
            am_item = Item(product)
            session.merge(am_item.db_item)
    else:
        am_item = Item(products)
        session.merge(am_item.db_item)

try:
    session.commit()
    print("Session Written")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Item Class:

```
class AmazonItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'amazon_products'
    timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    itemid = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String)
    upc = Column(String, index=True)
    msrp = Column(Float)
    price = Column(Float)
    brandname = Column(String)
    modelnumber = Column(String)
    url = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.itemid = item.asin
        self.name = item.title
        self.upc = item.upc
        self.msrp = item.price_and_currency[0]
        self.price = item.price_and_currency[0]
        self.brandname = ""
        self.modelnumber = ""
        self.url = item.offer_url


class Item():
    item = None
    db_item = None
    store = ""
    itemid = ""
    name = ""
    upc = ""
    msrp = 0
    price = 0
    brandname = ""
    modelnumber = ""

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.item = item
        self.db_item = AmazonItem(item)
        self.store = "Amazon"
        self.itemid = item.asin
        self.name = item.title
        self.upc = item.upc
        self.msrp = item.price_and_currency[0]
        self.price = item.price_and_currency[0]
        self.brandname = ""
        self.modelnumber = ""
        self.url = item.offer_url
        self.asin = item.asin

        if self.msrp == 0 or self.msrp is None:
            self.msrp = self.price

        if self.price == 0 or self.price is None:
            self.price = self.msrp

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.itemid == other.itemid

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(('itemid', self.itemid))

    def writetocsv(self, file):
        csv_writer = CSVWriter(file)
        csv_writer.addrow(self.getrow())
        csv_writer.write()
```

Comment: Would be useful to see Item class code

Comment: I added the Item Class

Comment: does the script crash on session.merge or session.commit? what database/db driver are you using?

Comment: It crashes on merge before the commit. The database is MySQL and the driver is myql_pymysql

Comment: Without any error message it is hard to say.Actually, it is very strange that there is no error. I suggest to make a detailed log (or print) and see what "item" is causing this and continuing from there. I also suggest to try using different database and driver (e.g. PostgreSQL) for testing. And also different machine to run the code. That way you can rule out the culprit.

Comment: It can be also an issue of IDE, if you are using one. Check that too

Comment: I also suggest to enclose the merge clause within try/except and try to print the exception by yourself.

Comment: I've tried putting merge in a try/except with no luck. I also tried running the code outside the ide. Trying it on a different machine was my next step, but haven't had a chance to try it yet.